# How to search for nil results with Rails SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, null

I have a model `User` with an `Address` attribute. I want to run a query that includes users with nil Addresses.

The following query:

```
User.where(address: nil)
```

returns a correct result of 2. But this one:

```
User.where('address = ? AND address = ?', nil, nil)
```

returns 0.

Is there something wrong with my syntax in the second query?

Here's the SQL query actually being run in my server:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM "users" WHERE (address = NULL AND address = NILL)
```

I suspect it's supposed to say "address IS NULL" not "address = NULL"

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE address IS NULL`?

Comment: Both should work correctly as of rails 3.  Can you show the mysql generated by the second?

Comment: @JoeMorano In that case, the reason you're seeing zero results from the second query is because `NULL` can't be equal to anything - not even to another `NULL`.  `WHERE (anything) = NULL` will always give no results.  You should use `WHERE address IS NULL` instead.

Comment: @NickEllis Added it to my question.

Comment: @Siyual How do I translate that into a rails query?

Comment: @JoeMorano Unfortunately, I don't know anything about rails.  But from the syntax, I would assume `User.where('address is null AND address is null')` (though, I'm not sure why it's a repeated condition.)

Answer (score 1):

The default in AR is to `AND` conditions so

```
User.where(address: nil).where(address: nil)
```

will generate a correct query.

Comment: again not sure on the Repeated condition, assuming you meant to look for another nil / null column.     It gets a bit trickier if you need to `or` the columns. but it can be done in AR as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax you're looking for:

```
User.where('address IS ? AND address IS ?', nil, nil)
```